# How do i include a module in the binary executable with chicken scheme

Tags: chicken-scheme

I have `(load "foo.import.scm")` and when i compile everything works, as long as i execute the program from the same directory. Otherwise it complains about not being able to find "foo.import.scm"

```
Error: (open-input-file) cannot open file - No such file or directory: "foo.import.scm"
```

if i do

```
csc -s foo.scm  -emit-import-library foo
```

and then

```
(import foo)
```

it compiles fine but then complains about

```
Error: (require) cannot load extension: foo
```

when run from a different directory

if i do

```
(use foo)
```

then it complains about

```
Error: (require) cannot load extension: foo
```

when I run it from a different directory.

What is the correct way to load this module into my program such that it will be included in the executable? Should be passing a different flag to `csc` ? The docs are not making the solution clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

`load` is by definition a runtime thing.  It's basically `(eval (cons 'begin (read-all)))` (with the caveat that CHICKEN can also `load` binary `.so` files). `load` will always load from the current directory, unless you use an absolute path.

If you want to use the module in a compiled program, don't load the import library; the compiler will do that automatically when you `(use)` the corresponding module.

Maybe you can explain a little bit more about your project structure? The question isn't exactly clear on what goes where.

Comment: project structure: 3 files in same dir `main.scm` `foo.scm` `foo.import.scm`

I then `csc main.scm`  I want the resulting executable to work from other directories. I've tried `import` `load` and `use` and all work locally but not in other directories when i execute the resulting binary.

Comment: There are several ways to do that: 1) Install `foo` as a global extension so that it can be found. 2) Install `foo` into a local directory as an extension using [deployed mode](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Deployment), with `rpath` set to that directory. 3) Use `-private-repository` to set `rpath` to match the directory where it is installed. 4) Compile your program separately and link it together, as units (see the [multi-file example in the manual](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Using%20the%20compiler#an-example-with-multiple-files)).